# Which last name should the children of Robert and Cersei pass to their children

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

For example with King Joffrey, he is (I know, I know he really isn't) the descendant of Houses Baratheon and Lannister, so because of that which last name is he passing to his children?

In my country we have two last names, the one of the father and the one of the mother. So my name is **Name last1 last2** and I only pass my first last name to my children, so for example my wife's name is **Mom_Name Mom_last1 Mom_last2** and my children they all will have **Child_Name last1 Mom_last1**, so only the *House* of the father is passing through time.

Maybe it is different in your countries, that's why I wanted to explain that.

I understand if the last name they pass may be the one with more importance, but it should be a rule, because if not the great name of *House Lannister* could be lost (Jaime can't have children and Tyrion is not welcome in the family).

Comment: The Lannister name would survive through Tywin's siblings and their children; see http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kevan_Lannister#Family

Comment: Yeah, but i don't think Tywin would be very happy about it, and also it won't be the *main* family.

Comment: Westeros is enough like Britain that Joffrey could use a [double-barrelled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name) surname, Baratheon-Lannister. (Of course, he could use Lannister-Lannister and be more accurate.)

Comment: not a dupe, but related to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19910/why-is-cersei-commonly-referred-to-as-cersei-lannister-instead-of-cersei-bara?rq=1

Comment: @sjl But we don't see any double-barrelled names in practice in Westeros. It works more like in the Middle Ages, not modern Britain.

Comment: It is clear from the books that children get their father's family name (or one of the bastard surnames, barring that). The "great" _House Lannister_ conceded that the surname wasn't important the minute they decided to make no overt bid for the Throne, and chose to manipulate _House Baratheon_ instead. This is one minor disadvantage of ruling from the shadows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the US and much (but not all) of Western Europe, the father's family name is passed on to the children.  This is a tradition going back centuries and is (at least where I live) the "expected" thing to do.

So, just as Robb Stark is not a Tully (his mother's family name) Joffrey should legally be a Baratheon, not a Lannister.

In terms of inheritance, Jaime should be first in line, followed by Tyrion.  I'm not sure where Cersei stands, since I don't know whether women can inherit.  If she can't, I would expect the lands/money/what have you to pass to her children *even though they are not Lannisters* since they are descended from them.  Just as the Iron throne went to Joffrey rather than Stannis or Renly, offspring seem to take precedence over siblings in this political system.

Comment: so, for example who will get the heritage of Tywin Lannister, lands, gold, etc., if they should always go to a Lannister?

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: In Westeros, a female only inherits if there are no other males inheritors on her same *level*. So if *both* Jaime and Tyrion cannot inherit, then Cersie inherits. If for any reason Cersie cannot inherit, the inheritance goes to the closes male relative, and so on.

Comment: Jaime dropped out of succession when he became a Kings Guard - that's for life. Tyrion is the only legal successor. But it will be interesting to see who will back his claim...

Comment: @SystemDown: So who would be the next heir after ADWD without Cersei and Tyrion?

Comment: @MartinSchröder - If all of Tywin's children are out of the picture, I presume the heir will either be Kevan's boy (forgot his name at the moment) or Tommen, but I'm unsure who takes precedence.

Comment: @SystemDown: But Tommen's father was King Robert. :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder - Yeah, but his mother (which we are completely certain of) is Cersei. So he *could* inherit through his maternal line. I'm just not sure if that precedes Uncle Kevan's male progeny.

Comment: It is Tommen. Only if all of Tywins legitimate descendants are dead does it pass to a sibling.

Comment: +1 This. No need to speculate at all; we _know_ in Westeros children get their father's family name, or if bastards, one of generic surnames such as Snow, Sands, etc. Comparisons to the real world are unwarranted, since the author already provides the answer in-universe.