# Who is now the Lord of Casterly Rock?

Tags: game-of-thrones, laws

I am re-watching Game of Thrones and I came across this question.

Tywin Lannister is the Lord of Casterly Rock - But since his death, who is now the Lord of Casterly Rock?

1. Tyrion can't be the Lord as he is a fugitive.
2. Jaime Lannister cannot be the Lord either as he's in the order of the Kingsguards.
3. There is no indication that it's Cersei.

Has this ever been mentioned? I imagine that since Tywin's death, there would be a lot of enemies who will see this as a weakness and try to take this land?

Comment: The Vassals of House Lannister haven't yet forgotten fate of Houses Reyne and Tarbeck to try and rebel against the lions. And enemies of House Lannister are all but destroyed on every compass point except south (high Garden and Dorne).

Comment: Why is it not the Imp? That's a pretty important assumption.

Comment: @TylerH Tyrion is an attainted traitor.  Unless and until that is overturned he's out of the line of succession.

Comment: You should define what *now* means (At the end of first 5 books/seasons?). Otherwise all the answers are going to get obsolete once GRRM (probably) starts to kill Cersei's children. *Gold shall be their crowns and gold their shrouds*.

Comment: We do not currently know. Probably a castellan rules in Cersei's name. Did Kevan have sons? One of them would suffice.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Let's begin this answer with [a quote from GRRM](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Category/C91/P210/):

> The short answer is that the laws of inheritance in the Seven Kingdoms
>   are modelled on those in real medieval history... which is to say,
>   they were vague, uncodified, subject to varying interpretations, and
>   often contradictory.

With that being said, [Cersei](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Cersei_Lannister) is the [current Lady paramount of the Westerlands](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Lannister) by both the show and the books.

[Kevan](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kevan_Lannister) and his proginy can't ascend to throne of the Kings of the Rock while a Child of Tywin's body is alive and free to claim his/her rights.

Lannisters are Andals who practice faith of seven. According to Andal traditions, rights of a son come before an elder daughter. Similarly rights of a daughter come before rights of an uncle. So the claimants with their number in Line of succession to Throne of Kings of the Rock would be (Ideally):

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║      Claimaint     ║ Number in Line ║ Remarks          ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║   Jaime Lannister  ║        1       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Tyrion Lannister  ║        2       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Cersei Lannister  ║        3       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Joffrey Baratheon ║        4       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Tommen Baratheon  ║        5       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Myrcella Baratheon ║        6       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║   Kevan Lannister  ║        7       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Lancel Lannister  ║        8       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Martyn Lannister  ║        9       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Willem Lannister  ║       10       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║   Janei Lannister  ║       11       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Tygett Lannister  ║       12       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║   Tyrek Lannister  ║       13       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  Gerion Lannister  ║       14       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║      Joy Hill      ║       15       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║   Genna Lannister  ║       16       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║     Cleos Frey     ║       17       ║ Ideal Conditions ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

But in reality and by legal impacts, the line of succession becomes this as per show:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║      Claimaint     ║ Number in Line (Books) ║ Number in Line(Show) ║                      Remarks                     ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   Jaime Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║    Disinherited as per vows of KG- See spoiler   ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Tyrion Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║ Disinherited and wanted for murder of his father ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Cersei Lannister  ║        Incumbent       ║       Incumbent      ║                   Current Lady                   ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Joffrey Baratheon ║           NA           ║          NA          ║                       Dead                       ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Tommen Baratheon  ║            1           ║           1          ║               See Spoiler at bottom              ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Myrcella Baratheon ║            2           ║          NA          ║         Dead as per show, alive in books         ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   Kevan Lannister  ║            3           ║           2          ║               See Spoiler at bottom              ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Lancel Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║     Disinherited due to joining the Sparrows     ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Martyn Lannister  ║            4           ║          NA          ║  Killed by Lord Karstark in show, alive in books ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Willem Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║              Killed by Lord Karstark             ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   Janei Lannister  ║            5           ║          NA          ║               Not mentioned in Show              ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Tygett Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║                       Dead                       ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   Tyrek Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║   Missing, presumed Dead. Not mentioned in show  ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  Gerion Lannister  ║           NA           ║          NA          ║                       Dead                       ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║      Joy Hill      ║           NA           ║          NA          ║          Bastard - Ineligible to inherit         ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   Genna Lannister  ║            6           ║           3          ║  Tywin's sister, don't know if mentioned in show ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║     Cleos Frey     ║           NA           ║          NA          ║                       Dead                       ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

By filtering out dead and disinherited characters, we get the following line:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║      Claimaint     ║ Number in Line (Books) ║ Number in Line(Show) ║           Remarks          ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║  Cersei Lannister  ║        Incumbent       ║       Incumbent      ║        Current Lady        ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║  Tommen Baratheon  ║            1           ║           1          ║    See spoiler at bottom   ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ Myrcella Baratheon ║            2           ║          NA          ║   Dead according to show   ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║   Kevan Lannister  ║            3           ║           2          ║  See spoiler at the bottom ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║  Martyn Lannister  ║            4           ║          NA          ║ Dead according to the show ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║   Janei Lannister  ║            5           ║          NA          ║  Not mentioned in the show ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║   Genna Lannister  ║            6           ║           3          ║             NA             ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Jaime can't be lord because of his vows. Tyrion is an attainted traitor and wanted murderer besides. That leaves us with Cersei. With her death, the seat will pass to Tommen No-Kidding-Baratheon unless Tyrion lands in Westeros with Daenerys and makes sure that his sister does die.

In the books, she appoints [one of her cousins](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daven_Lannister) as acting Warden of the West and [another cousin](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Damion_Lannister) as Castellan of Casterly Rock while she resumes regency of Iron Throne in KL. She refuses to go to Casterly Rock when her uncle reminds her that she is the lady of the Rock and her place is there.

Can't say if they have included this in show but even in show wiki, Cersei is the current lady of Casterly Rock.

Following are two family trees providing a visual info of claimants and their status.

### Line of Succession as per Show

[image]

### Line of Succession as per Books

[image]

**Spoiler Alert:**

> According to [Epilogue of A Dance with Dragons](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Epilogue), Kevan is dead at
>  hands of Varys. Which means he is also out of the race with his son
>  Martyn now 3rd in LoS and daughter Janei 4th. His sister Genna ascends to 5th

**Show Spoilers for Season 6 Episodes 6 & 10:**

> Tommen dismissed Jaime from Service as Kingsguard. He is now eligible
>  to inherit the Rock and thus is the heir apparent as per show canon given that Tommen has committed suicide and is thus eliminated from the line. Lancel was also killed in destruction of Sept of Baelor.

**Show Spoilers for Season 8 Episodes 6:**

> Cersei and Jaime died together along with their unborn baby. Which makes Lord Hand, Tyrion Lannister the last Lannister. Since he was cleared of all crimes and granted the position of the Hand under King Bran, it is evident that he is no longer attainted and is therefore the Rightful Lord of Casterly Rock and Lord Paramount of Westerlands, especially since we have no information otherwise.

---

**EDIT:** I did some further research w.r.t Books in order to find out Lannister claimants other than line of Tytos Lannister and link the other known Lannisters to the line.

Bear in mind that answer above deals only with the Line of Tytos Lannister.

Now moving back in Lannister family tree, We see that Grandfather of Cersei, Jaime and Tyrion, Lord [Tytos Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tytos_Lannister) had another brother named Ser [Jason Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jason_Lannister_(son_of_Gerold)).

Ser Jason fathered numerous children which include:

1. [Joanna Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Joanna_Lannister) who married her cousin, Tywin Lannister. Tywin was at that time heir to the Casterly Rock and Hand of the King. She died giving birth to Tyrion.
2. Ser [Stafford Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stafford_Lannister). He was killed by Lord Rickard Karstark in Battle of Oxcross.
3. [Damon Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Damon_Lannister_(son_of_Jason)). It is unknown whether he is alive or dead.
4. [Lynora Hill](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lynora_Hill). She is presumably alive however it is unknown who she married or if she had children.
5. 2 unnamed sons and 2 unnamed daughters.

Joanna, Stafford and Damon all had children and two of them at least had grandchildren. Joanna's children are of course the senior Branch and main line (Jaime, Cersei, Tyrion) along with their own descendants (Tommen and Myrcella).

Children of Stafford and Damon are listed below:

1. Stafford Lannister

   1. [Daven Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daven_Lannister)
   2. [Cyrenna Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cerenna_Lannister)
   3. [Myriella Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Myrielle_Lannister)
2. Damon Lannister

   1. [Damion Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Damion_Lannister)

      1. [Lucion Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lucion_Lannister)
      2. [Lanna Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lanna_Lannister)

Lanna Lannister is married to [Lord Jast](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Antario_Jast) and her children are unknown along with children of her cousins.

So according to books, after the line of Genna Lannister and her Frey descendants, we get the following (known) people in line of succession:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║      Claimaint     ║ Number in Line (Books) ║ Number in Line(Show) ║             Remarks             ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║   Damon Lannister  ║            7           ║          NA          ║  Eldest son of Jason Lannister  ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║  Damion Lannister  ║            8           ║          NA          ║                NA               ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║  Lucion Lannister  ║            9           ║          NA          ║                NA               ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║   Lanna Lannister  ║           10           ║          NA          ║       Married to Lord Jast      ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║   Daven Lannister  ║           11           ║          NA          ║                NA               ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║  Cyrenna Lannister ║           12           ║          NA          ║                NA               ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ Myriella Lannister ║           13           ║          NA          ║                NA               ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║    Lynorra Hill    ║           NA           ║          NA          ║ Bastard - ineligible to inherit ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

A visual description of Jason's line will be:

[image]

Bear in mind, none of these characters are mentioned in the show.

Comment: If it's revealed that Tommen is the son of Jaime, would his claim take precedence over Cersei's? I suppose that's opening a can of worms, considering he'd then be a bastard, yet also King of Westeros...

Comment: @TylerH Dont take my word on that, but I'm pretty sure that revealing he's Jaime's son would brand him as not only a bastard, but also the product of incest. Chances are he'd be taken down instantly.

Comment: Tommen Baratheon is presumably disqualified because he's king. When Robert became King, his brother Renly became Lord of Storm's End. (It clearly should have been Stannis, one reason that Stannis hated Renly.)

Comment: @PeterShor Robert did not have to relinquish his holding of Stormlands. He chose to create two cadet branches of house baratheon based in stormsend and dragonstone by granting those lands to his brothers. Is there any canon reference to there being a law that King can only hold KL?

Comment: @TylerH Not really. That would make Tommen a bastard with no claim at all, let alone having a superior claim than his mother.

Comment: Under the Targaryens, [Dragonstone](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonstone) was held by the heir to the Iron Throne (so not quite by the current king). And Robert gave Dragonstone to Stannis and Storm's End to Renly. Thus, there is no precedent for the king also being head of a Great House, and I don't see any good reason for the Lannisters to break with tradition (unless there's only one Lannister left alive).

Comment: Am I misremembering the books, or is Myrcella Baratheon's death unique to the show?  I thought she was only badly injured.

Comment: This is accurate as per [Comprehensive Rules for Game of Thrones Lines of Succession](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37862/21267)

Comment: @Mooz Yes, her death is unique to the show, among many other changes. Some minor, some major. They also changed Ramsay's wedding party as well as Stannis' fate and totally left out Lady Stoneheart.

Comment: @PeterShor Maegor the cruel never appointed a Prince of Dragonstone as he was fighting a war against his nephews the Princes Aegon and Jaehaerys (Later Old King)  and never had a son of his own. So yup, Targaryen Kings also chose to bestow Dragonstone on their heirs, they weren't compelled to.

Comment: @Wildcard I added clarification for myrcella

Comment: @NSNoob Wow.. Thank you very much for your extensive answer, much appreciated :)!

Comment: I really think you need to put in a bit more effort with your answers. I mean, seriously, talk about phoning it in... ;-) *(Great answer.)*

Comment: Its not a kingship to be lord of Casterley Rock so Kevan probably is Lord of Casterley warden of the south

Comment: @turinsbane why would Kevan be Warden of the South? Mace Tyrell remains warden of the south and his sons Willas and Garlan will follow him. Besides, Paramount lordship of either of the seven Kingdoms is virtually a kingship with the King on Iron Throne virtually an Emperor. Still that is only a matter of style, I do not see how does a title being a Kingdom affect theLoS

Comment: I think Cersei being queen would probably make Jamie lord of Casterley Rock

Comment: @turinsbane That's like saying that Robert becoming King made Stannis Lord of Stormlands. Cersei is still Lady of Casterly Rock until she decides to bestow her titles on her brother and abdicates from those offices in his favour.

Comment: You know too much about Game Of Thrones :P

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing You're too kind.

Comment: Why are the descendants of Genna and Emmon Frey not included here? If Genna herself can inherit then why can't her descendants inherit?

Answer (score 3):

Kevan Lannister was the acting lord of the Casterly Rock, before Twyin was murdered.

I believe Tywin always wanted to believe that Jaime will assume the title.  <s>If it does not happen, Lancel Lannister is the first on the line of succession.</s>

Lancel is also ineligible due to choosing Faith over family. It should go to some other member from the male member of the Lannisters.

Comment: @C.Kova - Was this ever mentioned in the tv series? Or have I just missed this point? Thank you for your answer:)

Comment: Lannisters aren't Ironborn who exclude women from line of succession. A child of Tywin still lives and isn't disinherited by vows or deeds. That Child is Cersei Lannister.

Comment: @NSNoob Tyrion explicitly wanted the Rock from Tywin as his birthright. Tyrion is younger than Cersei, so if the Rock is his birthright at one point, it means they exclude women from the line of succession. The only family, to the best of my knowledge, who do not distinguish women from line of succession is Dorne.

Comment: Andal Custom says Younger Son comes before Elder daughter. Jaime and Tyrion are both younger than Cersei but they still are ahead of her in line of succession. What's your point? Jaime can't take the seat  because of his vows and Tyrion is a murderer to be executed, thus attainted and a traitor to the crown. Which is why Cersei is the lady.

Comment: As to Tyrion's demand, you answered it yourself. Tywin always wanted Jaime to be his heir. Even after Jaime took his vows, Tywin never accepted that. He despised Tyrion and in his mind Jaime is his heir. Tyrion only demanded it because with Jaime out of the picture, he was the heir by sole virtue of being a male, thus having precedence over his elder sister

Comment: Also, even though I don't watch the show but I do believe that as per show Kevan was in fact in command of Lannister armies in Riverlands at time of Tywin's death. Later he becomes hand of the King and serves in KL. So how come he becomes lord of CR and how does his son come before him in line of succ?

Comment: Lancel, being a sparrow, forsook all claims to Casterly rock.

Comment: @NSNoob I never heard of that Andal Custom you referred to. The only other house in a succession crisis is the Starks, but Robb stated if Robb dies Jon should be the next Lord Stark, not some lord from the Eyrie. They did not even mention Sansa, who was alive and unwed. Ironborns do not exclude women from their succession. They only preferred to have a kingsmoot (or queensmoot) in which Asha Greyjoy can take part. Dornish are the only one that explicitly explains the role of daughter in succession. Dorne also disobeys this "Andal Custom", by preferring elder daughter over younger son.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson I forgot Lancel choose Faith over family. It is my mistake.

Comment: First off, Jon can't be lord of winterfell. He is a bastard thus disinherited (at least in eyes of the world even if Robb legitimized him by his secret edict). Then there is the other twist, Jon being a targ, not a Child of Eddard. Which makes Sansa the heir (Or rickon when he returns). The Northerns are not Andals anyways, they are first men. Women did not take part in Kingsmoot either until Asha. Dorne disobeys Andal custom because they are Rhoynar, not Andal. (Except the Stone-Dornish)

Comment: Ever wonder why do they say **King of the Andals and the Rhoynar and the First men**?

Comment: @NSNoob Women may not take part in Kingsmoot until Asha does not imply women are forbidden to do so. Can you quote this Andal Custom from a chapter in the book, or from an episode in the series? I must have missed it.

Comment: @C.Koca Sure. Read "Princess and the Queen" & "The Rogue Prince". It describes how Criston Cole the Kingmaker was seen as defender of the Andal custom that rights of a son come before a daughter. Which was why many did not accept Rhaenyra Targaryen as Queen and sided with Aegon II. Which was also why Rhaenys Targaryen (Daughter of Prince Aemon Targaryen) passed over in Great Council of 101 and Prince Viserys Targaryen was chosen as heir instead of his cousin Princess Rhaenys Targaryen.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, in the show when Robb and his banner men are discussing whether to support Stannis or Renly, Rob says that Renly can't inherit over Stannis because Stannis is older.

They never mentioned that Stannis's daughter has more claim over Renly, this would have been a big deal, because rather then being second in LOS, Renly would have been third.

Women in medieval times did not inherit because they do not remain within their house. A perfect example is the fact that all of Cersei's children are surnamed 'Baratheon'.

Why would house Lannister ever be ruled by a Baratheon when there are still Lannisters to rule it?

I would assume it would pass to Kevan due to this.

Comment: They never mentioned that Shireen did not have a more stronger claim than her uncle Renly either. IF Stannis had ascended to the Iron Throne, he would have made Shireen Princess of Dragonstone (At least in the books, In the show after all House Baratheon is now extinct). They were only discussing who to support in WOFK.

Comment: Also, this is not a first time that some other dynasty took control of another dynasty. Usually the new holder takes the name of the other family i.e. in this case Lannister. Tommen can't do that as he is the King as well, which remains a Baratheon. If you read history of House Lannister, this won't be first time that House Lannister continued from female line. Male direct line of House Lannister died out long ago when King Gerold III Lannister died without a son, his grandson from his only daughter, Ser Joffrey Lydden became King of Westerland and renamed himself Joffrey Lannister

Comment: So, House Lannister today is in fact descended from House Lydden even though there were Lannisters of Lannisport still when Joffrey Lydden was chosen. Tommen may choose to bestow the seat on Kevan Lannister but that would be his royal prerogative, he wouldn't be compelled to as he is direct descendant of the former Lord Tywin Lannister.

Comment: I see, well I have one more thought. If cersei is in fact the head of house Lannister now then why does kevan treat her like she's nothing speciall? Before he became hand he made this statement to cersei, "I do not recognize your authority to dictate what is and is not my concern. You are the Queen Mother. Nothing more!" At this point Tywin is dead so cersei would be head of the house.

Comment: can't speak for the script writers. One speculation would be while Kevan gave fealty to his brother, he never swore any allegiance to Cersei. Thus he is not bound to serve her as he is no longer sworn to Casterly Rock.

Answer (score 0):

Ser Daven Lannister, son of Stafford Lannister is acting Lord of Casterly Rock. Well he is in the books which should translate to the show as there is no one else eligible

Comment: The show version of Game of Thrones is different enough that this isn't at all certain.

Answer (score -2):

Didn't Jaime get released from his vows and the kingsguard by Tommen? Therefore he would be allowed to inherit both title and land. I believe **Jaime** should be back up to the top of the list now as an eligible heir to the Lordship of Casterly Rock.

Comment: Bear in mind this is not a new question, but an answer that has a statement of clarification.

Comment: See the content under the heading **Show Spoilers for Season 6 Episodes 6 & 10:**