# Does Joffrey have cousins?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Cersei tells Jaime they're the last of the Lannisters who count. Dumb question: Any nieces/nephews? You know, Joffrey/Tommen/Myrcella have any cousins or something?

Comment: Well, Tywin's children are Jaime, Cersei and Tyrion. Jaime and Cersei only had children together (and all of these are dead), and Tyrion has none (except possibly bastards). So there are no first cousins. More distant relatives would probably be classed (by Cersei) as Lannisters who don't count.

Comment: Like Kevan? (Who I guess may be dead anyway?)

Comment: Dead Martyn and Willem Lannister.

Comment: Tons. The Lannisters are actually a large family.

Comment: Joffrey/Tommen/Myrcella are all their own cousins...

Answer (score 10):

Does Joffrey have any cousins? A first cousin? No, he had one, the lady Shireen Baratheon who died. Second and third cousins? Yes he does from his maternal side but they are not discussed extensively in the show. Does Cersei have extended relations? Not that we know of from the Show.

Cersei said:

> they're the **last of the Lannisters who count**

Notice the Words who count. Those who count are the senior line of House Lannister i.e. the Line of Tytos Lannister. Of those, only Jaime and Cersei are alive (Tyrion is too but of course as per Cersei, he doesn't count). That doesn't mean they are literally the last of the thousands of year old Lannister dynasty.

Cersei indeed has distant cousins in the senior line, the descendants of Ser Jason Lannister. There is also a cadet dynasty, the Lannisters of Lannisport.

Most of those are not discussed in the show that I know of except Willem and Martyn Lannister, both of whom are dead. There's  also Lancel Lannister, who is dead as well. All three were sons of Kevan Lannister, Cersei's uncle. Line of Jason Lannister and Genna Lannister is not mentioned in the show. There was also that [show-only cousin, Orson Lannister](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Orson_Lannister), who as per Jaime and Tyrion loved to Crush bugs but he is dead as well. Ser [Stafford Lannister](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Stafford_Lannister) and his death were also mentioned in season 2, another one of Cersei's uncles.

As for her kids having cousins, of course they did. There was Shireen on Baratheon side, who is dead. None on the Lannister side as Jaime and Tyrion never married. There are second cousins of sorts who are listed in the linked answer but from book POV.

### The full extended Lannister family as described in the books

You can learn about the [extended Lannister family of Casterly Rock](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/128221/54887) here if you are interested, from books POV of course. I could rehash it here but there is no point as I have already written all that there - but these family trees from that answer might give you an overview (If you feel confused by these trees, refer to the linked answer for clarification):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Myrcella isn't dead?

Comment: @Tashus She isn't in the books. Somebody added the book trees here from my linked answer and I can't view editing history on phone. I expected there might be confusion if I added the trees here without the context. Which is why I didn't.  Please go to the linked answer for details and context.

Comment: aren't his maternal and paternal side the same?

Comment: @Jorrit Not _officially_. Officially their paternal side is Baratheon.

Comment: yeah officially, shouldn't you make note of princess Shireen Baratheon in that case??

Comment: @Jorrit There is a mention of her. `Does Joffrey have any cousins? A first cousin? No, he had one, she died.` But I agree I could have been more explicit in this regard.

Comment: oooh ok my bad :p sorry

Comment: wait... could it actually be said that joffrey's siblings were also his cousins? (not by legal terms but by biological terms)

Comment: @Termatinator Far from the most inbred Joffrey. Joffrey Velaryon's mother Queen Rhaenyra was a cousin to her youngest sons Aegon and Viserys since their father was her uncle Daemon. _That_ Joffrey's half siblings would be his second cousins since Joffrey's father's was ostensibly Laenor Velaryon who was son of Rhaenys Targaryen. Rhaenys was a first cousin to King Viserys I, Rhaenyra's father. Oh and Rhaenys' mother Jocelyn Baratheon was her father Prince Aemon's aunt, so Rhaenys is her own cousin. Some Family trees are circles and let's just leave it at that ;)

Comment: Aren't we talking about Joffrey Baratheon/Lannister though? His uncle and father was Jaime while Cersei was his mother and aunt

Comment: @Termatinator We are. I just thought it would be fun to point out that Joffrey Baratheon isn't by far the most inbred Joffrey ever